# Swift 5, Alamofire, Combine, MVVM throws error

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, alamofire, combine

```
func fetchData(from endpoint:ScrapeAPI )->AnyPublisher<T, APIError>{
    
    return AF.request(endpoint.mockurl,
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: endpoint.parameters,
                      encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.prettyPrinted,
                      headers: endpoint.headers)
        
        .validate()
        .publishDecodable(type:T.self)
        .value()
        .mapError{_ in APIError.unknown}
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

enum APIError:Error {
    case decodingError
    case errorCOde(Int)
    case unknown
}

extension APIError: LocalizedError{
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .decodingError:
            return "Failed to decode the object from the service"
        case .errorCOde(let code ):
            return "\(code)- Something went wrong"
        case .unknown:
            return "the error is unknown"
        }
    }
}

var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

fetchData(from:ScrapeAPI.getScrape).sink(
    receiveCompletion: { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        case .finished:
            print("Success")
        }
    },
    receiveValue: { value in
        print(value)}

).store(in: &subscriptions)
```

This prints error "unknown". It reaches the  API and API responds with a body. It seems it is not getting published to T. Interestingly, Alamofire .responseJSON works. Ideally, I would like to verify T has new JSON data from API. How do I go about it?

Comment: Don’t map your error to .unknown, you loose the original error this way. Either remove that mapping or add a case that includes the original error

Comment: Mmm. I don’t know what to say. What you said is obvious. You wanna show me how ?

Comment: Something like `case decodingError(Error)` or like I said remove the mapping altogether and return Error instead.